# Using navigator.share() to detect mobile users?

Tags: javascript, mobile, web-share

I'm trying to detect if a user visiting my webapp is a mobile user or not.  I've seen various implementations ([example1](https://dev.to/timhuang/a-simple-way-to-detect-if-browser-is-on-a-mobile-device-with-javascript-44j3), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser), [example3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device)) but none of them seem to be foolproof or recommended.

I have never seen anyone mention checking `if (navigator.share)` as a method to determine if a user is on mobile or desktop.  The if statement correctly distinguishes between desktop and mobile users in my app ([source](https://github.com/akliang/cooklang-cookbook/blob/main/frontend/views/view_recipe.hbs#L141)).

Can I rely on this if statement check?  If not, what are the drawbacks to using this approach?

(Note: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.share) states that `navigator.share` only has 87% coverage, but what if I just assume that's "good enough"?)

Comment: From the linked caniuse, it looks like this is supported by Chrome and Edge on Windows and ChromeOS. Since those aren't mobile users, I'd say this isn't the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge on Windows supports the Web Share API, so this is definitely *not* a good method to distinguish mobile from desktop users. On modern Chromium browsers, you can simply call the following API:

```js
const isMobile = navigator.userAgentData.mobile;
```